# Looping through dictionary, setting with copy warning

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to loop through a dictionary of dataframes and compute the number of days that passed since the first date in the dataframe.

```
for k,v in df_dict.items():
    v['day'] = v.index - v.index[0]
```

However I get the following warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

What is a better way to make this calculation without the warning? I do not want to suppress or turn off the warning, I'd like to rewrite so it does not trigger that warning to begin with.

Comment: What the `df_dict` dataframe looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to explicitly create a deep copy, you can do:

```
for k,v in df_dict.items():
    v = v.copy()
    v['day'] = v.index - v.index[0]
```

Comment: This works if you replace v with df_dict[k]

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need a loop:

```py
df_dict['day'] = df_dict.index - df_dict.index[0]
```